# How to validate form fields with javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to do some simple form validation using javascript object values. I know it's not "ideal", but I'm just working with a simple form that doesn't need to be iron-clad.

Please see my fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/6dXd7/3/

I am trying to make sure that each form field has a value. If so, set the value for `myObj.fieldID` to `yes`.

Then, when the form is submitted, check every existing `myObj.XXX` and be sure all their values are `yes`.

In my example, I am having trouble creating the object, and I don't know how to cycle through all the objects when the submit button is pressed without specifying each one by name.

Here's the code in the jsfiddle example linked to above:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myObj = {};
    $("input.checkblank").blur(function () {
        var inputID = $(this).attr("id");
        var contents = $("input#" + inputID).val();
        if (contents == "") {
            $(myObj).data(inputID, "no");
        } else {
            $(myObj).data(inputID, "yes");
        }
    });
    $("#verify").click(function () {
        if (myObj.first && myObj.second == "yes") {
            // ***** Trying to get it to scan through ALL existing myObj's and make sure all their values are "yes" *****        
            $('.results').text('all good');
        } else {
            $('.results').text('not good');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="checkblank"><br />
<input type="text" name="second" id="second" class="checkblank">
<a href="#" id="verify">check</a><br />
<p class="results"> </p>
```

​
​

Comment: Why not use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

Comment: why are you using jQuery.data() on a plain object? That method is for attaching data to DOM elements as `data-attr` values.

Comment: jsFiddle is great for demonstrating your code but please also put your code in the post so that this question remains useful long after the link dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were storing field info in jQuery DATA and trying to check them later not in the same place...

```
var obj = {}
$(obj).data('a','1');
console.log(obj.a); //this will log null, cause there's no attribute 'a' in 'obj'
console.log($(obj).data('a')); //this will log '1' :]
```

instead do this, you should store you data in attributes from native object like this:

```
var obj = {}
obj['a'] = '1'; //obj.a = '1' work's too
console.log(obj.a); //now it log '1' :]
```

Also, your verification function is wrong.. it only check if `first` exists inside `myObj` and if `second` exists and is equal to `"yes"`. So your verification function should be something like this:

```
$("#verify").click(function() {
    var allFieldsOK = false;
    for ( var field in checkedFields ) {
        if ( !(allFieldsOK = checkedFields[field] ) ) break;
    }
    $('.results').text(  allFieldsOK ? 'all good' : 'not good' );
});
```

Here is an update to you jsFiddle, it is working for you purpose and should work if you add more input fields with the class `checkblank` :]
http://jsfiddle.net/6dXd7/5/

Comment: Please do not rely solely on jsFiddle for the full answer.  When the link goes dead, your answer will be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked yours a little bit but basically used it. Works good.

Comment: @Sparky672 thx, i've edited my question to keep it useful without jsFiddle :D

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
$("#verify").click(.........});
```

with this

```
$("#verify").click(function() {
    var flag=true;
    $('.checkblank').each(function(){    //check all elements with class checkblank
         if($(this).val().length==0)     //set flag false if anyone of them is blank
            flag=false;                 
    })
    if (flag)  {
            $('.results').text('all good');       
        } else {  
            $('.results').text('not good');
        } 
});
```

...it should work